# How to execute an .sql script from oracle server using c#?

Tags: c#, oracle11g

How to generate the script for a particular database after the tables have been modified in c# . For example for an sql server Script function from Microsoft.smo is called . How should it be done for oracle server ?

Comment: can you please show us your effort?

Comment: class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var srv = new Server(@"(local)\sql2k8");
            var db = srv.Databases["TestDN"];
            foreach (Table tab in db.Tables)
            {
                foreach (string s in tab.Script())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
            Console.Read(); I followed that for sql server but i wanted some help for the oracle server.